# Selenium WebDriver don't get new page after redirect

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

I Have this login page, so after pass keys and clicking login button, the webpage should redirect me to a new page with my session, and sometimes it does, but in most case, the `driver.title` by example, still having the title of the Authentication page and obiously this prevent me to find elements of the page that I'm looking for.

I Already try to `driver.get(correct url)` but didn't work.

Here are my WebDriver's options.

```
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
```

Remove this, this will not wait for page load to finish . So you might be trying to get title before the page is loaded

Comment: eager mode load the full DOM, only don't load the css

Comment: This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait until the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, and discards loading of stylesheets, images and subframes.